# No HomeUp button in actionbar with custom layout

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

I am trying to add up(homeup) button in actionbar. I have added parent activity option in manifest and **it works if I don't use custom layout**. My custom layout code is following.

```
actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
View view  = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.top_header_layout, null);
ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,ActionBar.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
actionbar.setCustomView(view, params);
actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionbar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

## layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/top_bar_logo"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

## Manifest

```
<activity
   android:name=".MoreDetailsActivity"
   android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
   android:parentActivityName=".AccountInfoActivity"
   android:label="@string/more_details">

   <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
       android:value=".AccountInfoActivity"/>
</activity>
```

Comment: What do want to do after adding the home button? Are your trying to navigate to previous activity or the MainActivity?

Comment: I want navigate to a specific activity. Sorry I should add the code of manifest.

Comment: Maybe `FILL_PARENT` are messing it up? Are you seeing your app icon on the left? What is you use `WRAP_CONTENT` instead?

Comment: I don't have app icon(in manifest). Imageview in custom layout visible in center of actionbar. I disable layoutparameter code but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

`actionbar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);`

with

```
actionbar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
```

Also use this `actionBar.setIcon(your_drawable);` in order to display your back icon.

Comment: Thank you for reply. It works but option should be ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP. Can you please edit your answer? I will check it as accepted answer.

Comment: to display back icon you should use actionBar.setIcon(your_drawable);

Answer (score 0):

**Do something like this**

Inside `onCreate` of the activity.

```
actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
View view  = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.top_header_layout, null);
ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,ActionBar.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
actionbar.setCustomView(view, params);
actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionbar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
actionbar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

Now in your `onOptionsItemSelected`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        //Your code here. In your case use Intent
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And if you want the hardware back button listener use something like this.

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    //Your intent here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But my homeup button is not visible. I don't have problem to catch click event.

Comment: actionbar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);     I have added this line in your code. Have you noticed?

Comment: Sorry I missed that. But unfortunately it doesn't work.